# Higher fps when executing game through gDebugger

Tags: optimization, opengl

Well, this is really odd. My game is running around 54-62FPS, which is really anoying when it goes below 60. When I run it through gDebugger to profile bottleneck I get an fps around 90-120! I'm positive I'm printing the fps right because when I run with gDebugger the print matches the value measured by the tool.

Does anyone know something about it?

SOLVED: My card config was set to let application resolve whether to turn vsync on or off. The game had it on, while gdebugger off, thus explaining the higher fps.

Comment: Is it possible that the debugger disable vsync?

Comment: That seems like it. Thanks! I forced vsync off in my gfx and got much higher fps, even more than with gdebugger problably due to the debuggers's overhead.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it )

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: My card config was set to let application resolve whether to turn vsync on or off. The game had it on, while gdebugger off, thus explaining the higher fps.